# $\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{-x^2}\int_x^{x+1/x}e^{t^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{-x^2}\int_x^{x+1/x}e^{t^2}dt$

This is problem from Spivak calculus 1994, chapter 18, 31.

The book gives following solution: simply apply Lhopitatal rule, but what puzzles me is the way numerator is differentiated.

So they got $e^{(x+1/x)^2}-e^{x^2}\over 2xe^{x^2}$

But I think it should be  $(1- 1/x^2) e^{(x+1/x)^2}-e^{x^2}\over 2xe^{x^2}$ . I think they are missing derivative of $x+1/x$. Am I wright or wrong?

P.S Could anyone please help me editing this question?

Comment: is it $$\frac{x+1}{x}$$ or $$x+\frac{1}{x}$$?

Comment: It is the second

Comment: the searched Limit is zero

Comment: How is it related to my question?

Comment: can you tell me what term did you differentiated?

Comment: $\int_x^{x+1/x}e^{t^2}dt$

Comment: the first derivative of your integral is given by $$\frac{e^{x^2} \left(e^{\frac{1}{x^2}+2}
   \left(x^2-1\right)-x^2\right)}{x^2}$$

Comment: this term must you multiply by $$e^{-x^2}$$

Comment: $\int_x^{x+1/x}e^{t^2}dt$  is my numerator. $e^{x^2}$ is demominator. I differentiate them separately by Lhopital

Comment: I will ask another question

Comment: then do it and ask

Comment: Why do we need to differentiate $x+1/x$?

Comment: Is it $\;e^{t^2}\;$ within the integral, **or else** $\;e^{-t^2}\;$ ?

Comment: DonAntonie it is $e^{t^2}$

Comment: PJK isnt it composition of functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $\;e^{x^2}\;$ is continuous everywhere so it has a primitive function, say $\;F\;$ , and then

$$\int_x^{x+\frac1x}e^{t^2}dt=F\left(x+\frac1x\right)-F(x)\implies$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x^2}\int_x^{x+\frac1x}e^{t^2}dt=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{F\left(x+\frac1x\right)-F(x)}{e^{x^2}}\stackrel{L'H}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)e^{\left(x+1/x\right)^2}-e^{x^2}}{2xe^{x^2}}=$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)\left(e^2+e^{1/x^2}\right)\right)-1}{2x}=0\cdot\left((e^2+1)-1\right)\cdot1=0$$

Comment: Isnt derivative of $F(x+1/x) = F'(x+1/x)*(x+1/x)'$ ?

Comment: @MarkoffChainz Good catch, thanks. Editing now

Comment: DonAntonio This was the entire reason I asked the question here

Comment: @MarkoffChainz The basic principle doesn't change: it something going to zero times something bounded, so the whole limit is zero.

Answer (score 3):

No need to do a complicated derivative.

We can clearly assume $x>0$. Set $g(x)=x+1/x$ for brevity.

By the mean value theorem there exists $c_x\in(x,g(x))$ such that
$$
\int_{x}^{g(x)}e^{t^2}\,dt=e^{c_x^2}(g(x)-x)=
\frac{e^{c_x^2}}{x}
$$
Since $c_x<g(x)$ and the exponential is increasing, the integral is bounded above by
$$
\int_{x}^{x+1/x}e^{t^2}\,dt\le\frac{e^{g(x)^2}}{x}=e^2\frac{e^{x^2}e^{1/x^2}}{x}
$$
Then
$$
0\le e^{-x^2}\int_{x}^{x+1/x}e^{t^2}\,dt\le e^2\frac{e^{1/x^2}}{x}\le\frac{e^3}{x}
$$
By squeezing, the limit is $0$.